# animateWithDuration and change position notification

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am using `animateWithDuration` to move position of a view from origin to `x + somedistance`, but at the same time when I want an animation that will emit stars from that view during the movement to `x + somedistance.`

I tried using the below code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations^{
    [_view setFrame:destination];
    [emitStarsLibrary emitAtPoint:_view.frame.origin];
}];
```

Nothing happened. Stars are not emitting at changed position's point but If I am putting outside it, what the view origin is, stars just emit there. The problem is during the movement of a view, stars should be emitted where the view is. It should emit from 0 to whatever the destination view is moved.

How can I get position change notification or bind it with the `animateWithDuration`?

Comment: ... and what happened?

Comment: OK so what do you want?

Comment: can you move this line [emitStarsLibrary emitAtPoint:_view.frame.origin]; outside the animation and put it before it and try.. I believe you need to start the star animation at the old origin of the view.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Nothing happened. Stars are not emitting but If I am putting outside it, what the view origin is, stars just emit there. The problem is during the movement of a view, stars should be emitted where the view is. It should emit from 0 to whatever the destination view is moved. How can I get position change notification or bind it with the animateWithDuration?

Comment: I have a feeling you need to read about the different Core Animation *layer trees*: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW13